# ICON is not displaying from the start menu and also from Control Panel -> Programs and Features using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have tried many ways to show the ICON from the start menu and also from Control Panel -> Programs and Features. When I run the script in my local machine it is showing the ICON. But when I run this installer in other machines it's not showing the ICON. I tried the below methods but it is not showing the ICON in other machines. Is there anything wrong with my code? Please help me how to resolve this issue.

```
!define COMPANYNAME "Test"
!define APPNAME "Personal"
```

**Method1 To display Icon from Start Menu:**

```
InitPluginsDir
File /oname=$PLUGINSDIR\newicon.ico "\workspace\NULLSOFT\src\Bitmaps\ProductIcon.ico"

SetShellVarContext all
createDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}"
createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Test.exe" "" "$PLUGINSDIR\newicon.ico" 0
```

**Method2 To display Icon from Start Menu:**

```
SetShellVarContext all
createDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}"
createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\test.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Test.exe" "" "C:\NULLSOFT\src\Bitmaps\Test.ico"
```

**Method3 To display Icon from Start Menu:**

```
SetShellVarContext all
createDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}"
createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Test.exe" "" "C:\Program Files\NSIS\Contrib\Modern UI 2\Bitmaps\Test.ico" 1
```

**Method4 To display Icon from Start Menu:**

```
SetShellVarContext all
createDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}"
createShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Test.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\Test.ico" 0
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot store icons (or other permanent files) in $PluginsDir because this directory is deleted by the installer!

You would normally just put the icon in your .EXE but if you can't do that then you must extract the .ICO to $InstDir:

```
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File "c:\myfiles\MyApp.exe"
File "c:\myfiles\ProductIcon.ico"

CreateShortcut "$SMPrograms\MyApp.lnk" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe" "" "$InstDir\ProductIcon.ico" 0

WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\MyApp" "DisplayIcon" "$InstDir\ProductIcon.ico"
WriteRegStr ... write the other uninstall data.
SectionEnd
```

**During development** you might have to [refresh the shell icons](https://superuser.com/a/499079/658) or even [rebuild the icon cache](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-rebuild-the-icon-cache-in-windows/) if your previous attempts corrupted the cache.

Comment: Another alternative could be to get the image by referencing your application's main exe, then the icon assigned to it will be used for displaying on Add/Remove programs  `WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\myApp" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\myApp\myMainProgram.exe`